# How can I create a smooth colour change animation using swiftUI? (Example in question)

Tags: swift, animation, button, swiftui

I have a play/pause button that changes when pressed. At the moment it just fades in and out but I would like it to perform a animation that looks like the new colour is flowing over the old one.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
if(meditationViewModel.timerIsRunning){
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "pause")
        Text("STOP")
            .bold()
     }
      .padding()
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .background(Color.red)
      .cornerRadius(25)
      .shadow(radius: 20)
}else{
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "play")
        Text("PLAY")
            .bold()
    }
     .padding()
     .foregroundColor(.white)
     .background(Color.green)
     .cornerRadius(25)
}
```

The change of `meditationViewModel.timerIsRunning` happens elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - just use some shape (circle in this case) between text and opaque background and move it depending on state.

Prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

*Note: you can use just tap gesture instead of button and tune all parameters and colors, but in general the idea remains the same*

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var playing = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { playing.toggle() }) {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: playing ? "pause" : "play")
                Text(playing ? "STOP" : "PLAY")
                    .bold()
            }
            .background(
                Circle().fill(Color.purple)
                    .frame(width: 160, height: 160, alignment: .leading)
                    .blur(radius: 3)
                    .offset(x: playing ? 0 : -160, y: -40)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: playing)
            )
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .clipped()
            .shadow(radius: 20)
        }
    }
}
```