# How can I create an animation color change from center of a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I create an animation color change from center of a view in SwiftUI? (please see the below gif)?

[image]

So far I have tried adding an animation modifier to the view (please see the below code), but am not quite sure how to make the animation start at the center of the screen and flow to the outer edges of the screen.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color = Color.red

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            color = .green
        }, label: {
            
            Text("change background color")
        })
        
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(color)
    .animation(.default)
    
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw the maker of this is on reddit. He said he would [add a repo link](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/mi1311/animated_pokédex_app_created_with_swiftui/gt40fex?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) once he finishes.

Comment: You need same approach as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67074535/12299030.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two `Circle`s in a `ZStack` and animate the scale effect value of the top most circle.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private let colors: [Color] = [.red, .yellow, .blue, .pink, .orange]
    private let maxScaleEffect: CGFloat = 4.0
    private let minScaleEffect: CGFloat = 0
    private let animationDuration = 0.6
    private let animationDelay = 0.1

    @State private var shouldTransition = true
    @State private var colorIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(previousColor)
                .scaleEffect(maxScaleEffect)

            Circle()
                .fill(transitioningColor)
                .scaleEffect(shouldTransition ? maxScaleEffect : minScaleEffect)

            Button("Change color") {
                shouldTransition = false
                colorIndex += 1

                // Removing DispatchQueue here will cause the first transition not to work
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDelay) {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration)) {
                        shouldTransition = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
    }

    private var previousColor: Color {
        colors[colorIndex%colors.count]
    }

    private var transitioningColor: Color {
        colors[(colorIndex+1)%colors.count]
    }
}
```